# Does the traffic tunnelled using Stunnel on port 443:TCP appear the same as normal HTTPS to DPI?

Tags: tls, tunneling, socks5, dpi

I wrapped my `Socks5` traffic in TLS using [Stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) and the `Stunnel` server is listening on the port `443:tcp`.

I can connect successfully to `Stunnel` server and exchange `Socks5` traffic.

From the perspective of DPI (Deep packet inspection), is the traffic the same as regular HTTPS or they are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that with "regular HTTPS" you mean surfing the web using a web browser. In this case multiple target sites are involved, thus DPI can observe that connections to many different hosts are done. With Socks5 over TLS there is only a single or a few connections and only the a single or few Socks5 endpoints - which is easy to distinguish from "regular HTTPS".

Additionally with "regular HTTPS" many DNS questions are responses can be observed. This can even be observed when DNS ober HTTPS is used, because of characteristic traffic patterns different from visiting normal web sites. With Socks5 instead DNS resolution is often done by the Socks5 endpoint and not by the client.

Additionally the TLS stack of the client might be fingerprinted and compared to what common browsers usually have - see [JA3](https://engineering.salesforce.com/tls-fingerprinting-with-ja3-and-ja3s-247362855967/).